# Automapper - Mapping a property to a method

Tags: c#, automapper

I am currently working with classes that are defined as such:

```cs
public class User
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public int Age { get; private set; }
    public bool Active { get; private set; }

    public void Name(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public void Age(int age) 
    {
        Age = age;
    }

    public void Active(bool active) 
    {
        Active = active;
    }
}

public class UserDTO
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
}
```

I have configured my `mapper` as such:

```cs
MapperConfiguration config = new(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<User, UserDTO>();
    cfg.CreateMap<UserDTO, User>();
});
```

I have no control over the class `User` and will not be able to make any modifications to it.

```cs
var user = UserController.GetUser();
var userDTO = Mapper.Map<UserDTO>(user);
```

The above is how I usually do it from one direction, but now I want to be able to map
`UserDTO` back to `User` and because setting of values are done through methods instead, I am not sure how to go about it.

What I would like to be able to do is:

```cs
userDTO.Name = "John Doe";
Mapper.Map(userDTO, user);
```

and behind the scene, it would actually do a
`user.Name("John Doe");`

Comment: You're fine, AM works with private setters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have a special behaviour on creating a `Destination` instance out of a `Source` instance, you have to use the `.ConvertUsing()` method and manually create and fill your new (or existing) instance.

An example would be:

```
public class Source
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Destination
{
    private string _name;
    private string _id;

    public string Name { get => _name; }
    public string Id { get => _id; }

    public void UpdateName(string name)
    {
        _name = name;
    }

    public void UpdateId(string id)
    {
        _id = id;
    }
}

public class MappingProfile : Profile
{
    public MappingProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
            .ConvertUsing((source, existing, context) =>
            {
                // If existing is not null, the user called .Map() with an existing
                // destination instance, which should be filled.
                var dest = existing ?? new Destination();

                // Call special method to fill dest instance.
                dest.UpdateName(source.Name);

                // if mapper is needed for other (nested) mappings, it can be used
                var id = context.Mapper.Map<string>(source.Id);
                dest.UpdateId(id);

                return dest;
            });
    }
}

public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(c => c.AddProfile<MappingProfile>());
        var mapper = config.CreateMapper();

        var source = new Source
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
            Name = "Some name",
        };
        var dest = mapper.Map<Destination>(source);

        Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize(dest));
    }
}
```

Comment: The destination class in the question has private setters, so it would work by default.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu true, but it relies on an implementation detail and would bypass any logic in the public setter (granted there is none at this time). I would honor the API (horrid as it is) and map using the public "setters".

Comment: If you need the convenience, you use AM with private setters, otherwise I don't see how AM can possibly help, just write everything by hand.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu Also true, I don't see AM adding much value here.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu: Yes, I thought also, the default AM should do it for private setters, but I guess, there is more code in the special setter methods (cause this given code doesn't compile, due to double usage of same name for property and method). In that case (and / or private setters are not available) you have to take that route. It also doesn't give anything automatic, cause everything has to be done by hand, but at least you have only one place to do it (in the profile) and not cluttered over your code.

Comment: I guess the problem is the design. If you have a few update methods, DDD maybe, that makes sense, you don't need AM for that. But if you generate some silly methods to use instead of setters, then you have the worst of both worlds, you lose both the meaning and the convenience.

Answer (score -1):

Use following code, hope It will be helpful.

```
CreateMap<UserDTO, User>()
  .ForMember(desti => desti.Age, source => source.MapFrom(m => m.Age))
  .ForMember(desti => desti.Name, source=> source.MapFrom(m => m.Name))
  .ForMember(desti => desti.Active, source=> source.MapFrom(m => m.Active));
```

Comment: None of that is needed, the names match.